# UIAutomation get view

Tags: ios, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I'm playing with UIAutomation, and I can't reference a view...

Here is the log, where the view is visible: main_view

```
UIAApplication: name:MyProjectDemo rect:{{0, 0}, {1024, 768}}
UIAWindow: rect:{{0, 0}, {1024, 768}}
UIAElement: name:main_view rect:{{0, 0}, {1024, 768}}
```

How can I reference it and get their subviews ?

```
target = UIATarget.localTarget();
app = target.frontMostApp();
app.logElementTree();
mainWindow = app.mainWindow();

var view = mainWindow.views()["main_view"]; // doesn't work => undefined
var view = mainWindow.views()[0]; // doesn't work  => undefined
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As visible from element tree, its not a   `UIAView`   so you have to refer it as  `mainWindow.elements()["main_view"]`   .